# bash string length in a loop

Tags: bash

I am looping through a folder and depending on the length of files do certain condition. I seem not to come right with that. I evaluate and output the length of a string in the terminal.

```
    echo $file|wc -c gives me the answer of all files in the terminal.
```

But incorporating this into a loop is impossible

```
    for file in `*.zip`; do
    if [[ echo $file|wc -c ==9]]; then 
    some commands
```

where I want to operate on files that have a length of nine characters

Comment: You realise this is looping over all files that end with `.zip` in the current directory ?Unless you have put that extension onto text files it is unlikely to work .

Comment: It will "work" it will just be reporting the "size" of the zip file which may or may not be a meaningful statement here. Also `*.zip` does not want to be in backticks. It isn't an executable command.

Comment: That snippet also has a few other problems. You need a space between the `9` and the `]]`, a space between the `==` and the `9` and you need to wrap the `echo | wc` pipeline in `$()` to actually execute it. Having given us the errors you got from that snippet and having run it through shellcheck.net would have helped.

Comment: @EtanReisner I meant work how they want it to.

Comment: @JID They didn't get a clear indication of what "how they want it to" was supposed to be but yes it is somewhat unlikely to be reasonable this way.

Comment: @EtanReisner Next time i'll write `it is unlikely to work how you want it to(based on an assumption of how i think you would want it to work given the content in your question and similar questions i have seen in the past)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
for file in *.zip ; do
  wcout=$(wc -c "$file")
  if [[ ${wcout%% *} -eq 9 ]] ; then 
    # some commands
  fi
done
```

The `%%` operator in variable expansion deletes everything that match the pattern after it. This is glob pattern, not regular expression.

Opposite to natural good sense of typical programmers the `==` operator in BASH compares strings, not numbers.

Alternatively (following the comment) you can:

```
for file in *.zip ; do
  wcout=$(wc -c < "$file")
  if [[ ${wcout} -eq 9 ]] ; then 
    # some commands
  fi
done
```

Additional observation is that if BASH cannot expand `*.zip` as there is no ZIP files in the current directory it will pass "*.zip" into `$file` and let single iteration of the loop. That leads to the error reported by `wc` command. So it would be recommended to add:

```
if [[ -e ${file} ]] ; then ...
```

as a prevention mechanism.

---

Comments leads to another form of this solution (plus I added my *safety* mechanism):

```
for file in *.zip ; do
  if [[ -e "$file" && (( $(wc -c < "$file") == 9 )) ]] ; then 
    # some commands
  fi
done
```

Comment: Use `wc -c < file` to just get the value.

Comment: In this case `wc -c < $file`.

Comment: Nicely done; if you heed @fedorqui's advice, you can simplify to `if (( $(wc -c < "$file") == 9 )); then` (using _arithmetic_ evaluation allows you to use the usual operators); for robustness, please double-quote `$file`.

Comment: Whoooo... to far, that requires newest versions of BASH :-) I've grown on older ones.

Comment: From what I can tell, the `(( ... ))` syntax was introduced in Bash `2.04` (around 2000); for robustness, please double-quote all instances of `$file` in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

using filter outside the loop

```
ls -1 *.zip \
 | grep -E '^.{9}$' \
 | while read FileName
    do
      # Your action
    done
```

using filter inside loop

```
ls -1 *.zip \
 | while read FileName
    do
      if [ ${#FileName} -eq 9 ]
       then
         # Your action
       fi
    done
```

alternative to `ls -1` that is always a bit dangereous, `find . -name '*.zip' -print` [ but you neet to add 2 char length or filter the name form headin `./` and maybe limit to current folder depth ]

Comment: Background on why parsing `ls` output is not a good idea: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Your `find` command would search the entire _subtree_. With a simple pattern like `*.zip`, using simple shell pathname expansion (globbing) - `for f in *.zip; do ...` - is simpler, more robust, and more efficient. `while IFS= read -r FileName` would make your loop more robust.

Comment: agree, the core was not the ls/find but the loop and the filter